Why I get errors for `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` during `pg_dumpall | psql`?
I am migrating from PostgreSQL v15 to v16. During migration I got this error:
GRANT
ERROR:  function unaccent(text) does not exist
LINE 2:   SELECT unaccent(coalesce($1, ''));
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:
  SELECT unaccent(coalesce($1, ''));

CONTEXT:  SQL function "str_norm" during inlining
ERROR:  relation "banners_text_search" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT text from banners_text_search
                         ^
QUERY:  SELECT text from banners_text_search
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW

But If I add connection to my database, then migration done successfully:
GRANT
You are now connected to database "mydb" as user "postgres".
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW

The command I used:
docker exec -it postgres bash -c 'pg_dumpall --clean --if-exists -U postgres | \
  sed "/^REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW public.banners_text_search;/ i \\\\\\connect mydb" | \
  psql postgresql://postgres@empty.xxx.yyy.rds.amazonaws.com'

Why this error occured?
Why pg_dumpall does not create \connect mydb automatically?

Check the error message: unaccent() doesn't exists. Did you create this extension? And does it still exists or did you drop it later on?

@FrankHeikens: The create statement exists at the migration script. As I noted, if I add \connect mydb into the migration SQL between create function xxx and refresh materialized view, then everything works fine. For each of experiments I created a fresh PostgreSQL instance.

Spending another second on your question, banners_text_search also doesn't exist either.

pg_dumpall does create \connect statements in its output. My bet would be you have some more errors earlier on in the log, or perhaps something's failing quietly. You're not showing enough context.

@FrankHeikens: All objects exists. The trick is the addition of \connect mydb before REFRESH MATERIAILISED VIEW. No other errors happened.

@Zegarek: Yes, it generates, I even have one \connect mydb somewhere on the top. But without the added second one before REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW it does not work. No other errors happened.

To my knowledge, REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW is not part of the dump. How does it get into your dump? Could you create a simple example that shows us that the dump contains this command?

@FrankHeikens: https://imgur.com/a/fHLwXua This is screenshot of the output for pg_dumpall command above. First screenshot is the part where mydb dump is started, the second is where error occured, and the third is the last lines of dump.

Here is how migration looks when I added \connect mydb statement: https://imgur.com/a/QpvHkW5


The  unaccent extension is not installed for Postgres 16 or cannot be found. That needs to be resolved. 2) What is in the str_norm function? My suspicion is there some dependency in that there that is being run out of sequence. Postgres does not track dependencies inside functions.


You must be more selective in sharing information, as it is nearly impossible to help you. The error messages are obvious: a function and a relation do not exist in the database you're connected to. It's also strange that you want to change the dump before restoring it. To me, that's a compromised dump.

@FrankHeikens: May we meet via google meet? Then I could share the screen.

We can, just not right now, but send me a message on LinkedIn

@FrankHeikens. What is your timezone? I am available almost any work day after 11:30 Toronto time.

@EugenKonkov Los Angeles, PST. Just send me a message on LinkedIn
